# Adding a count from another table to existing query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This query is working fine:

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
                    posts.id as id,
                    posts.img_src as img,
                    posts.id_familia,
                    posts.tiempo,
                    posts.votos,
                    familias.clave,
                    familias.id as fm,
                    textos.clave,
                    textos.texto as familia,
            FROM posts,familias,textos
            WHERE posts.id_familia = familias.id AND familias.clave = textos.clave AND textos.lengua = ".detectarIdioma()." 
            and posts.id_usuario = $term 
            ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

But now I would like to add how many comments has a post, which is in the comentarios table.

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
                    posts.id as id,
                    posts.img_src as img,
                    posts.id_familia,
                    posts.tiempo,
                    posts.votos,
                    familias.clave,
                    familias.id as fm,
                    textos.clave,
                    textos.texto as familia,
                    count(comentarios.id)
            FROM posts,familias,textos
            JOIN comentarios ON comentarios.id_post = posts.id
            WHERE posts.id_familia = familias.id AND familias.clave = textos.clave AND textos.lengua = ".detectarIdioma()." 
            and posts.id_usuario = $term 
            ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

The thing is that the mysql error is

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM posts,familias,textos JOIN comentarios ON ' at line 12`

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT posts.titulo AS value,
  posts.id AS id,
  posts.img_src AS img,
  posts.id_familia,
  posts.tiempo,
  posts.votos,
  familias.clave,
  familias.id AS fm,
  textos.clave,
  textos.texto AS familia,
  COALESCE(COM_COUNT.NUM_COMMENTS,0) AS num_comments
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN familias ON posts.id_familia = familias.id
INNER JOIN textos familias.clave = textos.clave
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT id_post, COUNT(*) AS NUM_COMMENTS
      FROM comentarios
      GROUP BY id_post
    ) COM_COUNT ON COM_COUNT.id_post = posts.id   
WHERE AND textos.lengua = ".detectarIdioma()."
  AND posts.id_usuario = $TERM
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

This will left join with the number of comments per post, and if the JOIN is not matched will show 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
        posts.id as id,
        posts.img_src as img,
        posts.id_familia,
        posts.tiempo,
        posts.votos,
        familias.clave,
        familias.id as fm,
        textos.clave,
        textos.texto as familia,
        count(comentarios.id)
FROM posts INNER JOIN familias ON posts.id_familia = familias.id 
INNER JOIN textos ON familias.clave = textos.clave 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comentarios ON comentarios.id_post = posts.id
WHERE textos.lengua = ".detectarIdioma()." 
AND posts.id_usuario = $term 
GROUP BY posts.titulo,
        posts.id,
        posts.img_src,
        posts.id_familia,
        posts.tiempo,
        posts.votos,
        familias.clave,
        familias.id,
        textos.clave,
        textos.texto
ORDER BY posts.id DESC
```

You were just mixing two types of `JOIN` syntax. 
...and you'll probably need to group by every column except the one you're counting.

**EDIT:** To not restrict your results to only those with comments, you'll need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on that table.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time. Like this Query is working now, problem is I didn't think this through and is only returning posts with comments, I would like comments not to filter the query, just add the count of comments of each post, is that tricky?

Comment: I updated the sql (you may or may not need the `group by` - not sure about mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma before the FROM in the first query but not before the FROM in the second query